# Match values to columns in a Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, match

Assume I have a data frame df1 with columns A B C D and all zeros

```
A B C D E
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

And a another df2 with values for B and C

```
Name Value
B    5
D    2
E    1
```

I want that the values are assigned to the corresponding columns.
The result should be

```
A B C D E
0 5 0 2 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: First row only?

Comment: `df1[1, names(df1) %in% df2$Name] <- df2$Name`

Comment: I have many df2 and each one should go on a new line. I was thinking on using a loop... or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @prre72 what does "each one should go on a new line" mean? Wanted output that you posted has only first line modified

Comment: I mean that I will have e.g. df3 similar to df2 with values for A B C. those value should go into the next row of df1, etc...

Comment: @prre72 It's easy to do what you want, but can you please edit wanted output for more clearance

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple records, each in its own table, where each row consists of the name of the measurement and the corresponding value and the desired output should be a concatenated table, where each measurement has its own row and the columns represent the measurement types, then this should help achive it.

```
library(plyr) # for using rbind.fill

# sample data
df2 <- data.frame( name=c("B", "D", "E"), value=c(1, 2, 3) )
df3 <- data.frame( name=c("A", "E", "B"), value=c(2, 2, 8) )
df4 <- data.frame( name=c("B", "C", "D"), value=c(6, 5, 0) )
df5 <- data.frame( name=c("B", "A", "C"), value=c(7, 2, 9) )

# transpose each table and row bind them together
df <- rbind.fill( lapply( list( df2, df3, df4, df5 ), function(x) {
    setNames( data.frame(t(x[,-1])), x[,1] )
} )  )

# order columns in alphabetic order
df <- df[, order( names(df) ) ]
```

Of course, this can be built into the read in process.

```
# list files with our pattern
filename.list <- list.files( "df.*csv", path = "./" )
# read in and join them
df <- rbind.fill( lapply( filename.list, function(filename) {
    x <- read.csv( filename )
    x <- setNames( data.frame(t(x[,-1])), x[,1] )
}))

# order columns in alphabetic order
df <- df[, order( names(df) ) ]
```

**A more compact implementation using data.table:**

```
library( data.table )

filename.list <- list.files( "df.*csv", path = "./" )
dt <- rbindlist( lapply( lapply( filename.list, fread ), dcast, formula = '. ~ name' ) )[,-1]
setcolorder( dt, order( names(dt) ) )
```

Comment: wow that's great! what if I have 100 tables? can you build this using a loop?

Comment: Of course, you can build a list of data.frames using lapply.

Comment: Please mark the answer as solved if it is what you've wanted. Thanks!